# android - check which language text file (DE, EN) is loaded in the RAW directory

Tags: android

I've a text file in the RAW DIrectory

called test.txt

**My java Code checks correctly the test.txt** file with device language german. How can i check the EN-File, when the device language is english?

I think in line 3 of my code i have to set an if-else block to proof the raw directory?

THX a lot for HELP!

**My Java Code (works):**

---

```
     TextView HelpTxtMain;

     HelpTxtMain = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewMain);
     HelpTxtMain.setText(readTxtDe());


 private String readTxtDe() {

     InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);

     ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int i;

    try {
       i = inputStream.read();
    while (i != -1)
     {
      byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
      i = inputStream.read();
     }

     inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

   // TODO Auto-generated catch block

     e.printStackTrace();
    }

  return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rename the file to "test.txt" and put them into the directories `values-de` and `values-en` or better out the english file into the `values` directory to set the english language as the default language.

Android will select the right file based on the currient language.

Comment: Sry, i've written the false situation. I've only this one file in the raw directory. I need the same file in english language..how can i proof this in the java code like above? THX